# Can I insert debugger statements inside my Groovy code?

Tags: debugging, groovy, breakpoints

Both Ruby and Python have the ability of calling the debugger from code ( using the **ruby-debug** gem or the **pdb** module ). I'd like to know if something like that's available for Groovy.

I'm not interested in debugging with the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Groovy does not support this. If you want to debug your options are:

1. Start the groovy process by passing the debug arguments to the JVM. Once the process has started, use a command-line Java remote debugger
2. Use an IDE (IMO, IntelliJ has the best support for debugging Groovy)